# Laravel Controller Type Hinting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, type-hinting

After creating a model with -mcr (php artisan make:model Institution -mrc), the show function in controller was scaffolded as:

```
 /**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Organization\Institution  $institution
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Institution $institution)
{
    return view('institutions.show', ['institution' => $institution]);
}
```

The **return view...** was inserted by me. I was expecting it to have it populated with the object whose id was sent in the parameters.

```
/institutions/1
```

But, after using **dd($institution)**, I verified that it has the ID, not the object.

Shouldn't this variable return me the object?

Comment: can you put as your dd output here?

Comment: How is your route defined for show?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is called [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding). Your route will need to look something like:

```php
Route::get('institutions/{institution}', 'InstitutionController@show');
```

and then as per your controller

```php
public function show(Institution $institution) 
{
    return view('institutions.show', compact($institution))
}
```

You can read more on this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding).

I imagine your route had the parameter called `{id}` rather than `{institution}`.

Comment: The name of the route param, and the name of the param being passed to the controller's method must be the same for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the parameter of show function

```
public function show(Institution $institution) 
{
    return view('institutions.show', compact($institution))
}
```

becomes

```
public function show($id) 
{
    $institution = App\Institution::findOrFail($id);;
    return view('institutions.show', compact('institution'));
}
```

and in your routes
`Route::get('institutions/{id}', 'InstitutionController@show');`